# Use Azure Cognitive Search from on-premise

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

Team,

One of our client is using the Cognitive seach offering created using the Search SDK(Azure.Search.Documents) for their web sites hosted in Azure App Service. This is a multi layered text based search. Now they want to use the similar feature in on-premise for some internal apps hosted inside their on-premise environment. I am aware that the Cognitive Search has container offerings fo some of their Cognitive based services.

My query here is can i get the similar feature from on-premise using the Azure Search SDK, without having outbound connection from on-premise to Azure for Invoking the Cognitive Services Deployed in Azure? Or do we have any container based offering for Search, which can offer the similar feature? Does the Container offering is providing the the search feature too?

Thanks
TM

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use the Azure Search SDK without having an outbound connection from on-premise to Azure for invoking the Cognitive Services deployed in Azure. A containerized version of search doesn't exist.